# how to get user birthday from facebook sdk?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

How to get user birthday by `user.getBirthday()` ?

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() {
      // callback when session changes state
      @Override
      public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {

          // make request to the /me API
          Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

            // callback after Graph API response with user object
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
              if (user != null) {
                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getBirthday() + "!");
                Log.d("user_birthday","user_birthday:"+user.getBirthday());//user.getBirthday()  this value always is null?
              }
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all have you set permission for user_birthday? it's very important if you want to access user_birthday information

if the user is not null usually you can get the birthday by user.getBirthday()
because from what I see you're using the new facebook SDK

you can set permission for example when you using the facebook authbutton

```
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes"));
```

or you can reauthorize permission

```
Session.ReauthorizeRequest reauthRequest = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest(this, PERMISSIONS).
                    setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY).
                    setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
session.reauthorizeForPublish(reauthRequest);
```

Where The PERMISSION is an array containing your permission

Comment: what is authbutton ??

Answer (score 0):

Small tip: It is possible to request permissions with the initial open-session request, thus no need for re-authorization:

```
final Session.OpenRequest request = new Session.OpenRequest(Activity.this);
request.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("email", "user_birthday")); // Your permissions here
request.setCallback(new Session.StatusCallback()
{
    @Override
    public void call(final Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception)
    {
        if (session.isOpened())
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
});

Session fbSession = Session.getActiveSession();
if (fbSession == null || fbSession.isClosed())
{
    fbSession = new Session(Activity.this);
    Session.setActiveSession(fbSession);
}

fbSession.openForRead(request);
```

Activity.this - your activity context.

Hope this helps somebody.. :)