# Extended permission and Submission for Android App

Tags: android, permissions, location, date

I have perhaps a stupid question but I prefer asking. I am creating an App for Android and I use FaceBook Login process. I need:Birthday,Location
For that I have to submitt to Android/google my app to be allowed to have extended access rights to these information. The point I am blocking I have to attach my apk but my app is not finished and I do not implement yet birthday/location mechanism so is it mandatory to finish the app or/and I have to finish the code related to birthday/location before submitting ?
I would like to do some developper test around these features first.

Comment: When you said you need "Birthday,Location" are you talking about the Facebook permissions "user_birthday" and "user_location"??. If so, they have nothing to do with Google and you don't need to re-submit your app.

Comment: Yes I confirm your questions, so if I do not need to do something, it is strange because when I integrate Facebook API on Android I am able to receive basic information as Last Name/first name but for birthday day and user location it is not working, do you face this such issue ?. Previously I did for iOS and I have nothing to do. As Facebook dev center they said that I have to submit my app to have extended permission for these information.

Comment: Not sure if I am following correctly your question. You asked if you needed "to submit your app to Android/Google to have extended access to this information". The simple answer to that is no. If you are having issues getting the user birthday and location that may be an issue when you are requesting the permissions. You will need to specifically request those permissions from Facebook (Check this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494999/how-to-get-user-birthday-from-facebook-sdk).